# How do I access my Rails helper method in my view? "Nil location provided. Can't build URI"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create an app that returns a gif url depending on what the current weather at a location is. I'm using the open weather api and I am storing my urls in a hash in a module and creating a method that selects a gif url based on the weather code returned from the api call. For example, code 321 corresponds to "light rain" which and a gif depicting light rain should then be returned.

When I run my code I get an Argument Error `Nil location provided. Can't build URI` I'm not sure I'm accessing the the helper method in the right way. THe API call is working fine and I can return `@weather_code` to my view no problem. Any idea what is causing this? Here is my code:

forecasts_helper.rb

```
module ForecastsHelper
  GIFS = {
    thunder:
      {codes: [200, 201, 202, 210, 211, 212, 221, 230, 231, 232],
       urls: %w(
          https://media.giphy.com/media/26uf5HjasTtxtNCqQ/giphy.gif
          https://media.giphy.com/media/vS09bj1KrXwje/giphy.gif
          https://media.giphy.com/media/2pUAUd0cFntny/giphy.gif
)},
    light_rain:
      {codes: [300, 301, 302, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 321, 500, 501, 520, 521],
       urls: %w(
          https://media.giphy.com/media/xT9GEz2CeU9uaI2KZi/giphy.gif
          https://media.giphy.com/media/k28n1OPefBEeQ/giphy.gif
          https://media.giphy.com/media/H1eu9Vw957Rfi/giphy.gif

)},
    heavy_rain:
      {codes: [502, 503, 504, 522, 531, 511],
       urls: %w(
          https://media.giphy.com/media/1Yfxps0AHRYBR2tK2G/giphy.gif
          https://media.giphy.com/media/hk6czgfmwVJS0/giphy.gif
          https://media.giphy.com/media/26BGD4XaoPO3zTz9K/giphy.gif
)}
  }

  def find_gif_url
    GIFS.each do |key, value|
      if value[:codes].include? @weather_code
        value[:urls].sample
      end
    end
  end
end
```

forecasts_controller.rb

```
class ForecastsController < ApplicationController
  def current_weather
    @token = Rails.application.credentials.openweather_key
    @city = params[:q]
    if @city.nil?
      @forecast = {}
    else
      @forecast = OpenWeatherApi.new(@city, @token).my_location_forecast
    end
    @temperature = @forecast.dig('main', 'temp').to_i - 273
    @weather_code = @forecast.dig('weather', 0, 'id').to_i
  end
end
```

current_weather.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag(current_weather_forecasts_path, method: :get) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %><br>

<%= image_tag(find_gif_url, class: "gif") %>
```

Comment: Given the error message `Nil location provided. Can't build URI` I would guess that `OpenWeatherApi.new(@city, @token)` is failing. Is `@city` set? Do you pass a `params[:q]` to that controller?

Comment: @spickermann I don't think it's failing. If I have `<%= @weather_code %>` in my view I get the expected code for the corresponding city I search for.

Comment: @spickermann Yes, I'm passing the `params[:q]`. I've added the code to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are iterating through all `GIFS` but do not return when there is a matching code. Change

```
def find_gif_url
  GIFS.each do |key, value|
    if value[:codes].include? @weather_code
      value[:urls].sample
    end
  end
end
```

to

```
def find_gif_url
  GIFS.each do |key, value|
    if value[:codes].include? @weather_code
      return value[:urls].sample
    end
  end
end
```